# Data from Firebase not display in Swift 3 application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i can't retrieve data from firebase and show it on label, help me.

Firebase Data:

```
authentication-f5ddeaddclose 
 user_clicks
 X0KFbJAlrGUla9m1XebyhX0YZxB3
 Counts: 3
 nmsvVPmJWAbqPr0U4WbfHiqFMkE2
 Counts: 13
```

Firebase Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Xcode:

```
var ref:DatabaseReference?
var refHandle: UInt!




@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any)
{

    let user_counts: Int = counts

    ref?.child("user_clicks").child(userID).setValue(["Counts":user_counts])
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    refHandle = ref?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]

        print (postDict)
    })

    ref?.child("user_clicks").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary



        let user_counts = value?["Counts"] as? String ?? ""

        self.label_usercounts.text = user_counts

        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

When I open application, the lable does not display anything, just the text disappears. I don't know what to do, so may you help me please?

Comment: First thing to determine is if your snapshot is null. Can your print value ?

Comment: All is ok, it's shows. On another accounts also.

Snap (X0KFbJAlrGUla9m1XebyhX0YZxB3) {
    Counts = 228;
}

Comment: If the snapshot isn't null then your tablview is the issue. Post the code for your tableview. Also verify you can print user_counts

Comment: @DoesData I don't have tableview, i have only label, i want to change label text. When i print user_counts it's says error in shell.

Comment: Sorry I read label and table. Anyway can you print user_counts? If you can print the snapshot and not user counts then your error is in let user_counts = value?["Counts"] as? String ?? "" Why are you trying to cast it to a String? have you tried Int?

Comment: @DoesData Now when i'm trying convert to Int like this: `let user_counts = value?["Counts"] as? Int ?? ""` It's says "Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'String' ". If i delete '??' this makes more errors. Help please :(

Comment: The operator `??` allows you to provide a default value in case the variable before the operator contains `nil`. You need an Int default value instead of an empty string. I really don't know what your question is so I can't help you any further without more details. Consider adding what the snapshot contains and how your database is structured in your post